# Access asp.net MVC model from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to access my asp.net MVC model from angularjs. I can convert the model to a javascript object using `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` this works fine -I can access the object from the console in chrome.

Next I try to create a UL wit ng-repeat -this doesn't work. The UL does not appear on the page and there are no errors in the console. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/app.js"> </script>




<h2>Heading</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-app="app" ng-controller="editUser">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            var Permissions = model.Permissions;
        </script>

        <h4>UserSetting</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)



        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="permission in Permissions">
                <span>{{permission.Guid}}</span>
                <p>{{permission.SatelliteAccount}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And my app.js:

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('editUser', function ($scope) {



});
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat is repeating over $scope.Permissions, which is undefined. You cannot repeat over global variables, you need to define those on the angular scope in the controller.

app.js:

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('editUser', function ($scope) {

    $scope.Permissions = Permissions;

});
```